# Paging Library 3 problem when implement search with Room database

Tags: android, rx-java, android-paging-library, android-paging-3

I'm trying to implement a search query with Paging 3 Library. I can not find any example so currently, it looking like below.
The problem is after the search query result show 2 items, but after I'm clear the filter query, first it rendered the right data (40 items), but after a timed refresh invoked by the database, it show again the searched result (2 items), then 40 items, then 2 items (repeated)

I have tried to remove the line in Repository but didn't work.

```
PagingRx.cachedIn(contactListPaging, viewModelScope);
```

My query in DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM " +
"(SELECT * FROM contact WHERE type = 'NORMAL' AND block = 0 AND (uppercaseName LIKE :searchQuery OR tel LIKE :searchQuery) ORDER BY uppercaseName ASC)  " +
"UNION ALL SELECT * FROM " +
"(SELECT * FROM contact WHERE type != 'NORMAL' AND block = 0 AND (uppercaseName LIKE :searchQuery OR tel LIKE :searchQuery) ORDER BY uppercaseName ASC)")
public abstract PagingSource<Integer, Contact> getAvailableContactWithSearch(String searchQuery);
```

Repository

```
@Override
public Observable<PagingData<Contact>> getContactListPaging(CoroutineScope viewModelScope, @NonNull String searchQuery) {
    Observable<PagingData<Contact>> contactListPaging;
    Log.e(TAG, "getContactListPaging: searchQuery "+searchQuery +" "+searchQuery.isEmpty());

    Pager<Integer, Contact> searchContactPager = new Pager<>(
            new PagingConfig(PAGE_SIZE,
                    PREFETCH,
                    PLACEHOLDER,
                    INIT_SIZE),
            () -> mDao.getAvailableContactWithSearch("%" + searchQuery + "%"));
    contactListPaging = PagingRx.getObservable(searchContactPager);
    PagingRx.cachedIn(contactListPaging, viewModelScope);

    return contactListPaging;
}
```

ViewModel

```
@Override
public void loadContactList(String searchQuery) {
    Log.e(TAG, "loadContactList: searchQuery "+searchQuery );
    mDisposable.add(mRepository.getContactDataSource().getContactListPaging(ViewModelKt.getViewModelScope(this), searchQuery)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .subscribe(contactPagingData -> {
                contactListLiveDta.postValue(contactPagingData);
                swipeRefreshLiveData.postValue(ViewState.HIDE);
            }, error -> {
                AppLog.tagApp().e(TAG + " onError: ");
                swipeRefreshLiveData.postValue(ViewState.HIDE);
                contactListLiveDta.postValue(null);
            })
    );
}
```

I render it in View with

```
        mViewModel.getContactList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), contactPagingData -> {
        Log.e(TAG, "renderListContact: adapter size "+mAdapter.getItemCount());
        if (contactPagingData != null) {
            mAdapter.submitData(getLifecycle(), contactPagingData);
        }
    });
```

This is the log. First I searched with "999", the result is 2 items, then I'm clear the filter, the result became 40 items.

The problem was after cleared the filter, it shows 40 items, then shows 2 items, then shows 40 items is so weird. I do not change the filter, just showing the result.

```html
<p>2021-09-08 09:49:59.800 renderListContact: adapter size 40
2021-09-08 09:50:17.821 searchQuery 9
2021-09-08 09:50:17.958 searchQuery 99
2021-09-08 09:50:18.107 searchQuery 999
2021-09-08 09:50:18.312 loadContactList: searchQuery 999
2021-09-08 09:50:18.312 getContactListPaging: searchQuery 999 false
2021-09-08 09:50:18.325 renderListContact: adapter size 40
2021-09-08 09:50:20.712 renderListContact: adapter size 2
2021-09-08 09:50:20.719 renderListContact: adapter size 2
2021-09-08 09:50:20.722 renderListContact: adapter size 2
2021-09-08 09:50:23.752 searchQuery 99
2021-09-08 09:50:23.900 searchQuery 9
2021-09-08 09:50:24.070 searchQuery 
2021-09-08 09:50:24.273 loadContactList: searchQuery 
2021-09-08 09:50:24.273 getContactListPaging: searchQuery  true
2021-09-08 09:50:24.287 renderListContact: adapter size 2
2021-09-08 09:50:41.761 renderListContact: adapter size 40
2021-09-08 09:50:41.770 renderListContact: adapter size 40
2021-09-08 09:50:41.774 renderListContact: adapter size 40
2021-09-08 09:51:02.786 renderListContact: adapter size 40
2021-09-08 09:51:23.765 renderListContact: adapter size 2
2021-09-08 09:51:23.780 renderListContact: adapter size 2
2021-09-08 09:51:23.783 renderListContact: adapter size 2
2021-09-08 09:53:29.799 renderListContact: adapter size 2
2021-09-08 09:53:50.790 renderListContact: adapter size 40
2021-09-08 09:53:50.803 renderListContact: adapter size 40
2021-09-08 09:54:11.803 renderListContact: adapter size 40
</p>
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It turns out my bug was I subscribe every time when a new search query is entered and added to a ViewModel lifecycle Disposables, so the subscribe of the old query is still alive and refresh along with the new query subscribe. Fixed with dispose the old subscribe when having the new search entered

Comment: <pre>if (mSearchDisposable != null && !mSearchDisposable.isDisposed()){
            mSearchDisposable.dispose();
            Log.e(TAG, "loadContactList: mSearchDisposable " );
        }
        mSearchDisposable = mRepository.getContactDataSource().getContactListPaging(ViewModelKt.getViewModelScope(this), searchQuery) <code>

Comment: "Union ALL" is not efficient in general 

we can optimize if we used keyset pagination instead of offset limit pagination

But how do we use "keyset pagination" with paging 3 not aware
https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/